# How to interact with PyBullet GUI in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, popup, pybullet

I used the following code in a jupyter notebook

```py
p.connect(p.GUI)
```

which creates a popup window that looks like this:

[image]

Unfortunately, I can't interact with the window or the contents at all. Every time I scroll over it I get the Mac OS spinning rainbow wheel. I can't seem to even close it as I can't click on the red eXit button.

My questions:

1.) How do I just close the window? Do I have to do it using something like `p.connect(p.quit)`?

2.) Is there a way I can make it interactable? For example being able to click on the "Test" tab?

Comment: Have you seen [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/reinforcementlearning/comments/g2ln4x/rendering_pybullet_environments_in_jupter_notebook/) or [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/bulletphysics/bullet3/blob/656a1e74725933e947e5f64d465b62d6f9af683b/examples/pybullet/notebooks/HelloPyBullet.ipynb)? Those are both Colab, but may help with some of your issues. In general, something that has its own GUI is meant to run separate from Jupyter unless it has been adapted to play nicely together. I'll add that Colab is based on an old branch of Jupyter that has been very customized.

Comment: I also found [this on the pybullet support site from 2020](https://pybullet.org/Bullet/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?p=42839). See the notebook `MinitaurControlWithSliders.ipynb` in the zip file there attached to the post. I note that person was setting up a UI inside Jupyter using  [jupyter-ui-poll](https://github.com/kirill888/jupyter-ui-poll). That would seem to be adapting it to play nice together.